# Login with OTP is not getting capture in Azure AD Sign-In Log

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

We are not able to caputre User sign_In details, when user try to use "Login with OTP" in AAD >Sign-In Logs.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According  to [!NOTE]  in [azure-docs/view-audit-logs.md at master · MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs (github.com)](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/active-directory-b2c/view-audit-logs.md)

> You wont be able to see user sign-ins for individual Azure AD B2C applications
> under the Users section of the Azure Active Directory or Azure AD B2C
> pages in the Azure portal. The sign-in activity over there show user
> activity, but can't be correlated back to the B2C application that the
> user signed in to. You must use the audit logs to see the sig-in
> activity for that.

**Sign-in logs**

[image]

**Audit logs:**

---

[image]

And we need to note that Audit log events are  retained only for **seven** days.

**Reference:**
[signup-signin-with-phone-number - azure-ad-b2c/samples (github.com)](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/signup-signin-with-phone-number)